# angularjs + ng-repeat is not putting values on table

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying the response of a web API request.

I am assigning the reponse.data to a scope array.

The name of the array is $scope.MeetingTable.

You can see in the screen-shot:

```
$scope.MeetingTable = response.data;
```

[image]

in the html view:

```
<table class="table table-striped mt-4 mb-5" id="tblCrossReference">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Meeting ID</th>
            <th scope="col" width="20%">Agenda Item</th>
            <th scope="col" width="20%">Legistar ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="mt in MeetingTable">
            <td scope="row">{{mt.MeetingId}}</td>
            <td>{{mt.AgendaItem}}</td>
            <td>{{mt.LegistarID}}</td>
            <td>{{mt.Title}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Even-though I can see data in MeetingTable, there are no values in the table when the code finishes running.

I am not sure what might be the error. Am I assigning the response correctly? Is the ng-repeat wrong?

Thank you,
Erasmo

**UPDATE**

This is how I make the call

```
$scope.GetValue = function (meeting) {

    $scope.meetingId = $scope.selectedMeeting;
    var data = JSON.stringify({ 'meetingId': $scope.meetingId });

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/Meetings/Home/GetMeetingById',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

    }).then(function (response) {

        $scope.MeetingTable = response.data;
        
    }, function (error) {
        
        $scope.Message = 'An error occurred, please try again';
    });      
};
```

**C#**

```
public ActionResult GetMeetingById(Parameters data)
{
    using (MeetingEntities db = new MeetingEntities())
    {
        var meetingId = data.meetingId;

        List<MeetingObj> meeting = db.MeetingObj.Where(m => m.MeetingID == meetingId).ToList<MeetingObj>();
        
        return Json(new { data = meeting }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Returned Response**

contents of response

```
{data: Array(5)}
data: Array(5)
0: {MeetingID: 50162, AgendaItem: 1, LegistarID: 62597, Title: "Public Comment"}
1: {MeetingID: 50162, AgendaItem: 2, LegistarID: 62393, Title: "Rescinding Emergency Order #2"}
2: {MeetingID: 50162, AgendaItem: 3, LegistarID: 53601, Title: "Housing Issues"}
3: {MeetingID: 50162, AgendaItem: 4, LegistarID: 57765, Title: "Manager Report"}
4: {MeetingID: 50162, AgendaItem: 5, LegistarID: 59056, Title: "Policy Changes"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

[image: This is what I see after the code completes]

Comment: Is there an `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in the html? What do you actually see in the table?

Comment: @charlietfl - Yes, I placed the ng-app in the html tag, and the ng-controller in the body tag. I only see the headers of the table.

Comment: Could you show how you make the call

Comment: @Raxel21 - Will do updating my post. Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to change `$scope.MeetingTable = response.data => response.data.data;`

Comment: @Raxel21 - that was the fix! thank you so much!

Comment: @erasmocarlos I'm glad it worked!